# Change prompt style to minibuffer from GUI dialogs

Tags: minibuffer, mouse, prompt, gui

Emacs by default does not ask if you are sure you want to exit Emacs, so I added this to my configuration to prompt me to answer yes or no before quitting Emacs.

```
  (setq confirm-kill-emacs 'y-or-n-p)        ;; Confirm before killing emacs
```

I use `evil-mode` so if I try to exit with `:wq` or `:w` it does prompt me in the mini buffer, but (as I am a WM only user using DWM) if I press `Super+Shift+c` shortcut for my WM to close a program, it prompts me with a dialog instead of the minibuffer.

[image]

How do I set it so no matter what, always prefer the minibuffer, not just for prompting this, but for any kind of prompt, I would prefer the minibuffer. For example I have `mu4e` also setup for my Email, and every time I try to resync the mails, it asks for my GPG authentication passphrase, in a GUI dialog. I would also like that to be in the minibuffer, so I want this setting to be globally set.

Comment: FWIW the default behaviour is intended to react with GUI dialogs when you use the mouse to invoke a command, and the minibuffer when you use the keyboard.  Presumably Emacs can't tell the difference between "GUI window killed by mouse" and "GUI window killed by GUI window manager".

Comment: Yea, I figured that. Thanks for confirming I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled through the [`use-dialog-box` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dialog-Boxes.html). Either put this in your init file:

```
(setq use-dialog-box nil)
```

or use the Customize interface.

Comment: Though it's not involved specifically for this question, you might want to also mention option `use-file-dialog`.

Comment: @Gilles thanks `use-dialog-box` fixed the issue.

Comment: @Drew What is the `use-file-dialog` for? I mean when does it appears, I never until now saw it.

Comment: @apoorv569 It causes the OS's file-open dialog to be used instead of prompting for a file name in the minibuffer. But that only happens when file opening is triggered by a GUI actions such as a toolbar button or the menu (see the manual for details). And only if `use-dialog-box` is on anyway.

Comment: I see, I don't use toolbar, I have set the `tool-bar-mode -1`. I pretty much made Emacs look like Doom Emacs, as I was using it, before switching to vanilla Emacs. So I'm slowly learning how vanilla Emacs works.